# How do I change default MTU for lxdbr0 for containers created using LXD?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04, lxc, containers

I'm running Linux containers created by LXD on Ubuntu 14.04.05. I have a `lxdbr0` interface setup, but its default `MTU` is `1500`. How do I update it?

Answer (score 1):

At least in recent versions you can alter network interface configuration using the

```
lxc network set <network> key=value... [flags]
```

command.

E.g. to alter the MTU on an LXD-managed interface you might invoke

```
lxc network set lxdbr0 bridge.mtu=1234
```

Reference on things you can alter with the command: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/networks

Answer (score 0):

`ifconfig lxdbr0 mtu 9000` can be used to change the MTU.

Comment: Use `ip link set mtu 9000 dev lxbr0` instead. `ifconfig` is deprecated, and isn't even installed by default in the majority of modern distros. Be advised, this will only set your *running* configuration. However, if you have `ifconfig` installed, this will work.